# Wordpress select count query optimization

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance, woocommerce

We have a pretty large wordpress mysql database (9.8 GB)

rows in key tables:

- 770K wp_posts
- 14K wp_terms
- 4M wp_term_relationships
- 14K wp_term_taxonomy
- 16M wp_postmeta
- 1M wp_options (damn those transients)

I have a query I would like to optimize. I am struggling with this one for quite some time now. It is been used a lot at woocommerce based websites. I was wondering if someone could optimize this query.

```
SELECT  COUNT( DISTINCT ID )
    FROM  wp_posts p
    LEFT JOIN  
        ( SELECT  object_id
            FROM  wp_term_relationships
            WHERE  term_taxonomy_id IN ( 8128 ) 
        ) AS exclude_join  ON exclude_join.object_id = p.ID
    INNER JOIN  
        ( SELECT  object_id
            FROM  wp_term_relationships
            INNER JOIN  wp_term_taxonomy using( term_taxonomy_id )
            WHERE  term_id IN ( 20,21,31,46,3591,47,99 ) 
        ) AS include_join  ON include_join.object_id = p.ID
    WHERE  1=1
      AND  p.post_status = 'publish'
      AND  p.post_type = 'product'
      AND  exclude_join.object_id IS NULL
```

It is the query that recounts the products and is being found at the wc-terms-functions.php.

```
function _wc_term_recount( $terms, $taxonomy, $callback = true, $terms_are_term_taxonomy_ids = true ) {
global $wpdb;

// Standard callback.
if ( $callback ) {
    _update_post_term_count( $terms, $taxonomy );
}

$exclude_term_ids            = array();
$product_visibility_term_ids = wc_get_product_visibility_term_ids();

if ( $product_visibility_term_ids['exclude-from-catalog'] ) {
    $exclude_term_ids[] = $product_visibility_term_ids['exclude-from-catalog'];
}

if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items' ) && $product_visibility_term_ids['outofstock'] ) {
    $exclude_term_ids[] = $product_visibility_term_ids['outofstock'];
}

$query = array(
    'fields' => "
        SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ID ) FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
    ",
    'join'   => '',
    'where'  => "
        WHERE 1=1
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND p.post_type = 'product'

    ",
);

if ( count( $exclude_term_ids ) ) {
    $query['join']  .= " LEFT JOIN ( SELECT object_id FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN ( " . implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $exclude_term_ids ) ) . " ) ) AS exclude_join ON exclude_join.object_id = p.ID";
    $query['where'] .= " AND exclude_join.object_id IS NULL";
}

// Pre-process term taxonomy ids.
if ( ! $terms_are_term_taxonomy_ids ) {
    // We passed in an array of TERMS in format id=>parent.
    $terms = array_filter( (array) array_keys( $terms ) );
} else {
    // If we have term taxonomy IDs we need to get the term ID.
    $term_taxonomy_ids = $terms;
    $terms             = array();
    foreach ( $term_taxonomy_ids as $term_taxonomy_id ) {
        $term    = get_term_by( 'term_taxonomy_id', $term_taxonomy_id, $taxonomy->name );
        $terms[] = $term->term_id;
    }
}

// Exit if we have no terms to count.
if ( empty( $terms ) ) {
    return;
}

// Ancestors need counting.
if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $taxonomy->name ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term_id ) {
        $terms = array_merge( $terms, get_ancestors( $term_id, $taxonomy->name ) );
    }
}

// Unique terms only.
$terms = array_unique( $terms );

// Count the terms.
foreach ( $terms as $term_id ) {
    $terms_to_count = array( absint( $term_id ) );

    if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $taxonomy->name ) ) {
        // We need to get the $term's hierarchy so we can count its children too
        if ( ( $children = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy->name ) ) && ! is_wp_error( $children ) ) {
            $terms_to_count = array_unique( array_map( 'absint', array_merge( $terms_to_count, $children ) ) );
        }
    }

    // Generate term query
    $term_query          = $query;
    $term_query['join'] .= " INNER JOIN ( SELECT object_id FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} using( term_taxonomy_id ) WHERE term_id IN ( " . implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $terms_to_count ) ) . " ) ) AS include_join ON include_join.object_id = p.ID";

    // Get the count
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( implode( ' ', $term_query ) );

    // Update the count
    update_woocommerce_term_meta( $term_id, 'product_count_' . $taxonomy->name, absint( $count ) );
}

delete_transient( 'wc_term_counts' );
```

Could SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS be a better alternative? I am no query expert, please help.

Comment: Can you please provide an EXPLAIN output and the schema structure (relevant tables and the existing indexes)?

Answer (score 0):

Start by improving the many:many schema, as discussed here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is mostly a convenience so that you don't have to scan the table twice.  (And it is unclear how you might use it here.)

The query looks like a "explode-implode" situation where doing `JOINs` lead to more rows, then `GROUP BY` (or `DISTINCT` in your case) shrinks back.

I'm unclear on why you have `LEFT JOIN` in one case, but `JOIN` in the other.

Possibly each of the `JOINs` could be added to the `WHERE` clause in this format:

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT ... )
```

That would let you get rid of `DISTINCT`, thereby avoiding the explode-implode.  At that point, a simple `COUNT(*)` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function was called many many times every day and I there was no actual need to have a realtime update of the number of products I ended up recoding the function using a randomizer. Statistically out of 300 calls of the function it should run once (number 42), which is just perfect. Really managed to reduce the server load massively.

It is a WooCommerce core hack for now but I might write a plugin for this.

Here is the code :

```
function _wc_term_recount( $terms, $taxonomy, $callback = true, $terms_are_term_taxonomy_ids = true ) {
$number = rand(1,300);
if($number == 42) {
global $wpdb;

// Standard callback.
if ( $callback ) {
    _update_post_term_count( $terms, $taxonomy );
}

$exclude_term_ids            = array();
$product_visibility_term_ids = wc_get_product_visibility_term_ids();

if ( $product_visibility_term_ids['exclude-from-catalog'] ) {
    $exclude_term_ids[] = $product_visibility_term_ids['exclude-from-catalog'];
}

if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items' ) && $product_visibility_term_ids['outofstock'] ) {
    $exclude_term_ids[] = $product_visibility_term_ids['outofstock'];
}

$query = array(
    'fields' => "
        SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ID ) FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
    ",
    'join'   => '',
    'where'  => "
        WHERE 1=1
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND p.post_type = 'product'

    ",
);

if ( count( $exclude_term_ids ) ) {
    $query['join']  .= " LEFT JOIN ( SELECT object_id FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN ( " . implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $exclude_term_ids ) ) . " ) ) AS exclude_join ON exclude_join.object_id = p.ID";
    $query['where'] .= " AND exclude_join.object_id IS NULL";
}

// Pre-process term taxonomy ids.
if ( ! $terms_are_term_taxonomy_ids ) {
    // We passed in an array of TERMS in format id=>parent.
    $terms = array_filter( (array) array_keys( $terms ) );
} else {
    // If we have term taxonomy IDs we need to get the term ID.
    $term_taxonomy_ids = $terms;
    $terms             = array();
    foreach ( $term_taxonomy_ids as $term_taxonomy_id ) {
        $term    = get_term_by( 'term_taxonomy_id', $term_taxonomy_id, $taxonomy->name );
        $terms[] = $term->term_id;
    }
}

// Exit if we have no terms to count.
if ( empty( $terms ) ) {
    return;
}

// Ancestors need counting.
if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $taxonomy->name ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term_id ) {
        $terms = array_merge( $terms, get_ancestors( $term_id, $taxonomy->name ) );
    }
}

// Unique terms only.
$terms = array_unique( $terms );

// Count the terms.
foreach ( $terms as $term_id ) {
    $terms_to_count = array( absint( $term_id ) );

    if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $taxonomy->name ) ) {
        // We need to get the $term's hierarchy so we can count its children too
        if ( ( $children = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy->name ) ) && ! is_wp_error( $children ) ) {
            $terms_to_count = array_unique( array_map( 'absint', array_merge( $terms_to_count, $children ) ) );
        }
    }

    // Generate term query
    $term_query          = $query;
    $term_query['join'] .= " INNER JOIN ( SELECT object_id FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} using( term_taxonomy_id ) WHERE term_id IN ( " . implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $terms_to_count ) ) . " ) ) AS include_join ON include_join.object_id = p.ID";

    // Get the count
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( implode( ' ', $term_query ) );

    // Update the count
    update_woocommerce_term_meta( $term_id, 'product_count_' . $taxonomy->name, absint( $count ) );
}

delete_transient( 'wc_term_counts' );
}
else {}
```

}